# React: Get data from firebase and store using setState race condition

Tags: reactjs, firebase, setstate

It seems I have some sort of race condition with `setState` when reading data from Firebase. Upon loading the component, the listener `child_added` is invoked for as many as client records are in the table `clients`, but only the last client record is actually stored in the state using `setState`. I know this has to do with a lag in setState where it only works once the cycle ends, so there is a race condition with the multiple setState calls. How do I fix this so all the client records are stored correctly in `this.state.clients`?

```
class ClientsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      clients: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      let clientsRef = fire.database().ref('clients').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
      clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
        let client = snapshot.val();
        client.id = snapshot.key
        this.setState({ clients: [client].concat(this.state.clients) })
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any race conditions going as `setState()` enqueues a change for each time it's called, in this case each `client` snapshot resulting from the `child_added` event including existing `client` and new `client` added.

The issue really might just be with your syntax for `setState()` which may be mutating/reverting `this.state.clients` each time. Instead try using `spread syntax` `...` to append `client` objects to `this.state.clients` and update/merge `this.state` in an immutable way.

```
class ClientsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      clients: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const clientsRef = fire.database().ref('clients').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);

    clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      const client = { ...snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };

      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        clients: [...this.state.clients, client]
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Using a personal Firebase project I was able to get each item into the equivalent of `this.state.clients` and display those accordingly in both `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. If you are willing, you could create a dummy Firebase project with mock data/structure matching your actual project and generate a StackBlitz if it still doesn't work.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was nice but it didn't solve my issue. My issue happened when I was removing the element form the DOM and then adding it back. I resolved the issue by hiding the elements instead of removing and adding them back later. Not sure why but the problem only happens after removing and then adding the element back to the DOM. This issue didn't happen on the very first addition of element to dumb on startup. Why?

Comment: I think I have an idea of what may be going on, but would need to try it with a local project unless you can create a StackBlitz to demonstrate the issue with a mock Firebase project. Just to understand the issue completely, a couple of questions. Are you indicating there are multiple instances of component `ClientsTable` on a single view being added/removed? If so, are they **all** executing the same exact Firebase query as you have in your question or do they differ using something like Firebase's `orderByChild()` or `equalTo()`?

Comment: Or when you say "hiding the elements" do you mean the individual list items being returned from the Firebase list query? Is `ClientsTable` executing Firebase actions such as `push()`, `set()`, `remove()` on the items returned from the query within `componentWillMount()` in your question? You may need to update your question with additional information of the functionality of `ClientsTable`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to clear your references to Firebase, otherwise it will cause memory leaks. In React this is typically done in **componentWillUnmount**.

Using your example, you need to add the following:

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.clientsRef.off();
}
```

You will also need to modify your code in ***componentDidMount*** so that you use ***this.clientsRef***, instead of using a local variable.

You can read more about this on the [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/05/using-firebase-with-reactjs.html).